# Dynamic segments with default routes in Iron Router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

In Meteor, using iron-router, I'm trying to implement a route mapping which has a dynamic segment and a fallback route if the dynamic segment does not match any items in a collection. For example, say I have a URL like so:

http://foobar.com/harold

I would like to first check if `harold` matches any IDs in a `Posts` collection. If there is a match then it should take me to a `postPage` template.

If there are no matches, then the router should render `harold` matches any items.

I've searched through all the iron-router documentation, but can't seem to figure out the right approach. I wonder if there is something like `this.next()` which cancels the current route mapping and goes to the next route mapping. Here's my attempt to try to do it:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('postPage', {
    // matches: '/MFLS6aKqqRZ2JGz9q'
    // matches: '/81zBqGE85aAfjk1js'
    path: '/:postId',
    before: function () {
      //check if segment matches a post ID
      post = Posts.findOne(this.params.postId);
      if (!post) {
        //If no matches, then go to next route
        //Something like this.next()?
      }
    },
   data: function() {
      return Posts.findOne(this.params.postId);
   }
  });

  this.route('profilePage', {
    // matches: '/harold'
    // matches: '/brendan'
    path: '/:username',
    data: function() {
      return Profiles.findOne(this.params.username);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: So a username can never be the same as a tag? This seems like an unnecessarily confusing rule. Is there some reason why you cant just have a `/tags/:tag` route?

Comment: I edited my question to show a use case which makes more sense. The goal is to avoid having too many segments in the URL.

Comment: Anyone still looking for a solution to a similar issue should check out this post: http://meteortips.com/tutorial/iron-router-part-2 I found it super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is really just one route: `/:input` where `input` can be anything. As @David Weldon mentioned, this isn't a good idea; it basically subverts the point of using a router, and causes a lot of extra code and database queries to run every time the URL changes.

That said, if you really want to do it that way, you just need to collapse all your code into one route:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('theOneRouteToRuleThemAll', {
    path: '/:input',
    data: function() {
      if (Profiles.findOne({username: this.params.input}) != null)
        return Profiles.findOne({username: this.params.input});
      else if (Posts.findOne({postId: this.params.input} != null)
        return Posts.findOne({postId: this.params.input};
      else
        return null; // No user or post found; could handle with notFoundTemplate
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah I see your point about excessive database calls, I wonder if it would be more efficient to make sure all postIDs have a capital letter, and all usernames lowercase. Then use regex to parse the urls and route it appropriately.

Comment: That's pretty much what you achieve by using separate routes, i.e. `/posts/:postId` and `/users/:userId`. But yes, if you really want to avoid the `/posts/` or `/users/` segment you could find some other way to parse out `this.params.input` so that you know which collection to query, rather than needing to query both.

Comment: My goal is to keep the URLs as short as possible, so that there is a little less cognitive load for the user. Another thought was that I could enter a special character into the postId like a dash or exclamation mark. Or to simply use a URL shortener for posts, which would redirect to the long url. ;-)